# Update Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty 404 Not Found

Tags: updates, 17.04

I have tried looking up every possible Ubuntu update problem forum, however I cannot seem to find anything that works.  I cannot seem to figure out how to fix the issue where it keeps saying the packages or files with Zesty are unable to be found.  Below I have copied the code I get when I type in `sudo apt-get update`.

```
Ign:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fenics-packages/fenics/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease                 
Ign:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease               
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Err:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all Packages
Ign:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main Translation-en_US
Ign:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main all DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Note: I had to put a space between the two // after http since I guess I do not have enough reputation to post links

Comment: "Every possible?" It's been answered here at least four times *today*

Comment: I couldn't find anything that worked could you please post a link? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please upgrade to 17.10. 17.04 is no longer supported and will not receive, for example, security fixes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

End of life for 17.04 was January 13, 2018. The repositories have been moved to a different location and must be accessed differently.

You should upgrade to 17.10 or install a long term support version like 16.04. Then you can continue with whatever you were trying to do.

Comment: Answers to the OP's question are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: See this post for a soln: http://wimantis.ninja/fixing-ubuntu-17-04-apt-get-update-release-file-not-found/